# How many schemas (Limit) can I use in an instance of a SQL Server database and in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database-schema

I have to decide which method is better for us, in order to make our software a little more as a multi-tenant method, maybe I have to decide between using schema or only a Table "Tenants" and I have a question: how many schemas (limit) can I use in an instance of SQL Server and of Oracle?

Comment: You should be fairly safe with SQL Server; [*Database objects include objects such as tables, views, stored procedures, user-defined functions, triggers, rules, defaults, and constraints. The sum of the number of all objects in a database cannot exceed 2,147,483,647.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I'd really vote for a tenants table over multiplying all tables per tenant though, the maintenance only of schema changes in a few hundred duplicated tables shouldn't be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can have a maximum of 2,147,483,647 objects.

An object can be a table, view, procedure, etc., and also a **schema** is an object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: I don't think schema is a database object.It's a group of database.   http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216889&seqNum=2       .Also, the article you have shared ,nowhere the line is mentioned there that the schema is a database object

Comment: @ShiwanginiShishulkar A schema has an ID, and therefore is an object like tables, views, columns, etc. Try the command ``select * from sys.schemas`` . You can create, alter, delete a schema, and you can apply access rights on it.